# ffmpeg throws "cur_dts is invalid" error when trying to get stream from IP camera

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, rtsp, ip-camera

I'm trying to stream from an IP camera with the following ffmpeg command:

```
const command = [
        '-loglevel',
        'debug',
        '-timeout',
        '10000000',
        '-rtsp_transport',
        'tcp',
        '-i',
        this.cameraInfo.url,
        '-c:v',
        'copy',
        '-c:a',
        'aac',
        '-f',
        'mp4',
        '-movflags',
        '+faststart+frag_every_frame+empty_moov+default_base_moof',
        "-min_frag_duration",
        this.livestreamSegmentDuration,
        'pipe:1',
    ];
```

With this command I pass an output to another stream transformer and stream as HLS using "mp4" instead of "ts" to avoid transcoding.

Everything works smoothly with different cams, but when I try to get the stream from "Meldana" (issue is related to all ip cameras of this manufacturer), it constantly throws the following error and does not stream:

```
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:1 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
```

Even though it does not work with ffmpeg, I can watch the stream just fine in VLC.
What might be the problem? Is there anything that could be corrected in the ffmpeg command?